# what are the philosophical proofs of Tawheed in the maturidi and a'shari schools?

Tags: aqidah, tawheed

I come from a Christian backround but am considering islam.truly understanding classical theistic divine simplicity led me to Tawheed,but I heard that sunni islam rejects divine simplicity so I am confused to what proofs there are in your system for Tawheed?

I heard that in orthodox islam God's attributes are not identical or numerically the same as his essence(Though I heard that in the Maturidi it was but I don't think thats true,yet they deny absolute Divine simplicity),so it seems he can have posterior metaphysical parts wich make him up.
why then cannot there be one essence and three 'persons' or subsisting relations like the eternalist modalists hold(catholics) or even three essences giving rise to three persons each(like Social trinitarians believe)?
Am I wrong that God has parts in orthodox islamic schools like Maturidi or A'shari?

if God is absolutely simple,or if he is absolutely one it would follow that he is absolutely simple wouldn't it,and then it would follow that there can be no internal subsisting relations(like the FSH modalism of the catholics) in a absolutely simple being wich would be a step towards absolute monotheism.

But orthodox islam has denied this conception if I am correct?
From what angle would the orthodox muslim argue against the Trinity in it's two understandings(Eternal Father-son-spirit modalism of the classical theists and the veiled Tritheism of the Social Trinitarians who reject divine simplicity like Platinga and some modern protestants)is basically what I'm asking?

wouldn't a being who's essence is identical to its existance be absolutely simple?A being who's essence is not identical to it's existance is Created.the definition or synonym of a uncreated unconditioned being is a being that has its essence and existance as one and the same,yet from what I've studied this would lead to absolute Divine simplicity wich only the Imamiyah affirm?

What am I getting wrong here?and from your perspective as a a'shari or maturidi what are the lists of philosophical arguments for Tawheed against multiplicity of entities as subsisting relations in one essence as the catholics hold,and there being three unique essences and three persons as the social trinitarians hold?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to talk only about Sharia Islam, because it's the true Islam of Allah and Prophet Muhammad (pbuh), and the most logical one.

Allah is simply alone. He is the First One, the Creator of everything. To be the First One and the Creator of Everything else already makes God Unique and Completely Alone in terms of being a Diety and having partners.

In Islam, God is too Great to have a son (like the Jews and the Christians say He does), He isn't of our nature to have a son. It is very probably a disgrace to the Lord of the Worlds to have Jesus, a human, as a Son.

Islam that denies God as absolute strict Only God with no partners and sons whatsoever isn't Islam.

We don't know enough about God to say if He is absolute simple or not.

There are many philosophical arguments that say God is Unique. It's basically the most rational belief in supernatural. Why would there be multiple gods ? Isn't One enough ? Wouldn't they fight, and because by definition a god doesn't get tired and doesn't die and is infinitely powerful, wouldn't the universe absolutely collapse and nothing would work ?

Christianity was first same as Islam, just like was Judaism. It is the infidels who changed the Books of Allah (Bible and Torah) and changed the religions.

Some catholics confuse Jesus (Issa (as)) and believe he's God, some others believe He's the son of God. Some others believe in the holy trinity. All of this is very strictly condemned in Islam. All of this is a disgrace to God.

We should really think of God as a separate entity, an entity whose nature our small hypocrite minds can't handle, can't imagine. Trying to imagine God and trying to understand Him with our brains (which don't see the world in it's true way, the brain translates perception and anthropocentrism is created, *yay*) leads to illusions (believing in multiple gods, partners to Allah almighty) due to the abstract idea of an ideal God, that again, our mind can't fully understand. Our minds can't even imagine 1 million kilometers, how are they going to imagine God, which is infinetly more complex and different from us and the world we're used to know ?